# Evaluation error while trying to build model in DSX when dataset has a feature column with unique values

Tags: machine-learning, ibm-cloud, data-science-experience

I’m getting an evaluation error while building binary classification model  in IBM Data Science Experience (DSX) using IBM Watson Machine Learning if one of the feature columns has unique categorical values.

The dataset i'm using looks like this -

```
Customer,Cust_No,Alerts,Churn
Ford,1000,8,0
GM,2000,50,1
Chrysler,3000,10,0
Tesla,4000,48,1
Toyota,5000,15,0
Honda,6000,55,1
Subaru,7000,12,0
BMW,8000,52,1
MBZ,9000,13,0
Porsche,10000,54,1
Ferrari,11000,9,0
Nissan,12000,49,1
Lexus,13000,10,0
Kia,14000,50,1
Saab,15000,12,0
Faraday,16000,47,1
Acura,17000,13,0
Infinity,18000,53,1
Eco,19000,16,0
Mazda,20000,52,1
```

In DSX, upload the above CSV data, then create a Model using automatic model builder. Select Churn as label column and Customer and Alerts as feature columns. Select Binary Classification model and use the default
settings for training/test split. Train the model. The model building fails with evaluation error. Instead if we select Cust_No and Alerts as feature columns, the model is created successfully. Why is that ?

Comment: So. You are getting an unknown error when you are doing something not really explained. Show us what you want to do, what you tried, and what results you get. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @jdv Updated the problem description

Comment: Sounds like you should open a support ticket: https://console.bluemix.net/unifiedsupport/supportcenter

Answer (score 1):

When a model is built in DSX the data is split in training, test and holdout. These datasets are disjoint.

- In case the Customer field is chosen, that is a string field this must be converted in numeric values to have a meaning for model ML algorithms (Linear regression / Logistic regression / Decision Trees etc. ).

How this is done:
The algorithm is iterating in each value from field Customer and creates a dictionary, mapping a string value to a numeric value (see spark StringIndexer - https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-features.html#stringindexer).
When model is evaluated or scored the string fields from test subset are converted to numeric based on the dictionary made at training point. If a value is not found there are two options (skip entire record or throw an error - first option is choose by DSX).

Taking into consideration that all values from Customer field are unique , it means that none of the records from test dataset arrives in evaluation phase and from here the error that model can not be evaluated.

- In case of Cust_No, the field is already a numeric and does not require a category encoding operation. Even if the values from evaluation step are not found in training the values will be use as is.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a step back, it seems to me like your data doesn't really contain predictive information other than in `Alerts`.

The `customer` and `Cust_no` fields are basically ID columns, and seem to not contain predictive information.

Can you post a screenshot of your `Evaluation error`? I can try to help, I work on DSX.